Creating a superhuman medicine
In my story my character David suffers from a genetic disorder which makes his skin burn when exposed to the sun. Throughout his life he tries to look for a way to cure him of his disease. After a while he meets a doctor that gives him an experimental treatment to try to cure him. Although he’s not cured, the treatment does change him. He gained numerous abilities like enhanced strength, speed, regeneration, enhanced senses, and an increased lifespan.
During my story I want to include (or at least hint at) any real or possible medicines that give people these sorts of effects. So I’d like to know if there are any drugs or substances that — if combined — can make someone superhuman?

With all due respect to the respondents... asking how to describe magic via science is a popular question on this site, but it almost always fails because... well... magic. Despite the responses, no, there is no such drug(s). If there were such a drug, you'd be hearing about it on the nightly news including interviews about doping with the International Olympics Committee. At best, if you look up athletic doping scandals, you'll find a list of performance-enhancing drugs - but you'll find nothing that makes someone "superhuman." (*Continued*)

Nanites are a great sci-fi bio-enhancer.

... It's worth noting that there's a reason comic book writers use creative, interesting, and implausible reasons for their character origin stories - they know perfectly well that superpowers don't and can't exist, which means that trying to crowbar them into science ultimately fails by distracting the reader. Instead, they opt for creativity and imagination.

@JBH though I agree magic makes things difficult, we can still approach it. Magic does not exclude physics or technology. Creating a fireball out of thin air is impossible, but the effects of it being thrown can be explained by physics, if enough information is given as a basis. I think it was you as well who mentioned in a meta post that we should tackle more questions instead of dismissing them outright. My first sentence dismisses the magic and medicine, but I try to approach it as scientifically as possible. With current technology it is absolutely bonkers, but if we dream...

This sounds EXACTLY like what happened to Muzan in Demon Slayer: Kimetsu no Yaiba. Albeit, Muzan only burned after the treatment, I can't help but think this might be plagiarism of KnY.

I'm going to warn you right here and now, you are just bordering on plagiarism.
As @DekoRevinio stated in a comment, this is almost identical to what happened to Muzan in Demon Slayer Only difference I can see is the character's name and the fact that he (Muzan) did not burn until after the treatment was administered. So just please be warned.
But I will answer your question anyway.
One way to possibly make this work would be to make the treatment some kind of mythical herb, item, spirit item, etc. This would be too similar to what happened in Demon Slayer, so you probably shouldn't do this.
Another possible way to do this is if your story is set in the far future, you could use nano-robot technology. If you're focused more here in the present, you could try something akin (not identical) to testosterone or adrenaline, but you could state that it was a clinical breakthrough that cures skin conditions (this is where the not identical part comes in) and also allows the user to live longer. But as it turns out, the treatment actually causes your strikingly-similar-to Muzan character David to burn instead.

I’m guessing you’re aiming for plausible rather than a research study. I’ll see what I can do here.
The other answers here are great and bring up some good points genetic engineering editing or splicing are possible but take time and have limits, however given the character’s condition I would think (if I was a Dr.) of hitting the problem head. So direct application treatments of the thing I’m trying to fix. If he has a skin condition I’m going to try to fix his skin.
-New Skin-
Depending on how Sci-fi you want to go you might just give him new skin, or another layer of skin, synthetic of course this might be made from very tightly wound material that has a higher resistance than human skin, be anchored into the muscle layer act as a secondary outer musculature system, which might be able to provide some extra speed, strength and sensitivity. However, this wouldn’t be cheap nor simple, it would be military research program expensive, and I would imagine painful if its tapping into living nerves. It would not, however, give any extended life, or any internal benefits besides maybe advanced cooling and circulation.
-Implant-
Dr. puts an implant in his body likely near the base of skull or lower back. This gives you some wiggle room. As one of the others mentioned, our bodies have lots of natural things like adrenaline and such. Could an implant tell someone’s body to produce more of this and/or release synthetic versions of this and other compounds into the character’s body? Maybe, if we look at Neuro-link we can see a human interface is possible though costly and time intensive. But here I feel is the wall, unless the Dr. is being dishonest, and the character blindly signs up without a thought and asks zero questions I don’t see how this ‘treatment’ would fly.
-Other Options-
-They were never human-
They pass as human but never were and the Dr. just lets them know what exactly they are. Or had some hand in their creation from the get-go.
-Body Swap-
High sci-fi but it’s an option Dr. puts them in an engineered or non-biological body.
-They are just High-
Not sure how serious you want to be with this, so I give this one for comedic purposes. ‘Dr.’ gives them a sunscreen they’ve mixed with some kind of hallucinogens and or injects them with common illicit drugs and takes their money. Fun twist to hit the reader with when the drugs and sunscreen start to wear off.

Genetics
Medicine isn't magic. Treatments can't give you superpowers. As TheDemonLord says in their answer, it unlocks strength you already had at best. Unfortunately these limits on your own strength are for good reasons, damaging yourself in the process. You want to be able to be strong or happy the day after as well. With removing these limits, you can't be sure of that at all. Not to mention that the senses are more easily physically capped. Finally, there are good reasons to not mix many drugs. Though I can comfortably tell you, no mix of drugs will give you superpowers, nor will any out of control radiation therapy or the like.
If we're going sci-fi already, I would opt for genetical changes. Not only would this be able to tackle the actual disease, but the scientist can on purpose change the user in different ways. Nature has evolved to always renew itself to be able to tackle the next challenge the environment throws in nature's way, removing the need for life longer than one or a few times reproduction. In addition, it is survival of the fittest,not strongest. Nature saves energy where it can, which is why muscles atrophy when not used, or memories fade.
With genetics you could, theoretically, control it all. You can remove the limits or reduce other effects. Atrophy of the muscles slowed down to a crawl. Muslce growth becomes easy, making 'superhuman' strength feats much more easy. You can start tampering with how the eyes grow, increasing the rods and cones to resemble that of a jumping spider or eagle. You change the brain to (temporarily) be in a state of increased flexibility, like when you were very young, to be able to quickly adapt and learn all the new inputs and outputs, as to not overwhelm the person with new, poorly understood information. Maybe make much of the brain much more dense, as the frontal lobe is more like swiss cheese compared to the brain stem for example.
It would require a knowledge unheard of in science to pull that all off, tailored to the specific person. It wouldn't be a 'take today, resulting tomorrow' thing either. You probably want several phases where growth or changes are induced, capping them later. Many would also require action of the person as well, as for example proper muscle growth is also based on (micro) damages of the muscle cells sustained during activities.
That would mean it is a very intentional act on behalf of the scientist, adding in these changes in the cocktail put into the bloodsteam. The scientist might try to cure the disease as well, but simply not yet be as knowledgeable yet about this specific topic.

I mean Adrenaline + Testosterone + Other steroids will do a lot for increased Speed, Strength, Regeneration (to a degree) and Enhanced Senses.
The latter taken over time will increase all your basic attributes (Strength, speed etc.) and help you heal faster (which is why Steroids are prescribed for healing injuries)
Being able to dump a massive amount of Adrenaline into your system when you are engaged in superhero stuff can do wonders - There are numerous stories about Mums lifting up really heavy objects to save their children - the medical term is Hysterical Strength
However - Enhanced Lifespan is an issue.
Even if we assume Roid-Rage isnt real (there is some controversy as to whether this is a real thing or not - but I personally believe increased Testosterone = increased feelings of Aggression) - that cocktail of drugs - they are probably going to be dead by the age of 30 or 40.
Think of your body like a Car - if you service it regularly and drive at the speed limit, you might get 200,000 miles out of it before a major component fails (Engine, Transmission etc.) - whereas if you take it to a Trackday regularly and redline it, it will last a fraction of the time. Your body is the same - you cannot push it to the extremes of performance without paying a hefty price.
And as of yet - we have no cure or remedy for aging or for repairing long-term damage caused by things like Steroid use

The duration of the effect of a dose of adrenaline is measured in seconds, because of how adrenaline works. Yes, injecting testosterone regularly will increase your speed etc. to a certain degree, but definitely not by a lot; it might help an athlete improve their performance, but it will not transform a regular office worker into an olympic athlete.
